# Loop results from python into django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a simple application that queries a remote URL for a city code.

views.py

```
import requests
import json

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'app_sitecode/home.html', {'site_code':''})

def lookup_code(request):
    locode_url = 'https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/un-locode/code-list_json/data/05f6ccfe0cd03ab51bed07273b982df9/code-list_json.json'
    try:
        city = request.GET.get('city')
        r = requests.get(locode_url)
        raw_data = (json.loads(r.content))
        res = None
        for sub in raw_data:
           if sub['Name'] == city:
              res = sub
              print(res)
              print('')
              #break
              city_code = res['Location']
              country_code = res['Country']
              state = res['Subdivision']
              site_code = country_code + "-" + city_code
        return render(request, 'app_sitecode/home.html', {'site_code':site_code, 'name': city, 'country': country_code, 'state': state})
    except:
        return render(request, 'app_sitecode/home.html', {'cleartext':'', 'city':'INVALID CITY'})
```

When I query for a city, I get valid returns. For example I query the city Stoughton. I see that two Stoughton's were found (python output below). One is Stoughton, WI and one is Stoughton, MA.

```
{'Change': None, 'Coordinates': None, 'Country': 'US', 'Date': '9307', 'Function': '--3-----', 'IATA': None, 'Location': 'SOU', 'Name': 'Stoughton', 'NameWoDiacritics': 'Stoughton', 'Remarks': None, 'Status': 'RQ', 'Subdivision': 'MA'}

{'Change': None, 'Coordinates': '4255N 08913W', 'Country': 'US', 'Date': '0201', 'Function': '--3-----', 'IATA': None, 'Location': 'ZTN', 'Name': 'Stoughton', 'NameWoDiacritics': 'Stoughton', 'Remarks': None, 'Status': 'RL', 'Subdivision': 'WI'}
```

The struggle I am having is how to loop the results in the html file. Currently the html file prints only the last entry found.

home.html

```
{% block content %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'lookup_code' %}" autocomplete="off">
<div class="container">
<br>
    <!-- Text input-->

<form>
  <div class="form-row align-items-center">

    <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">City</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      </div>
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" value="Find It">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<br>
<h3> {{ site_code }} </h3>
<p><small class="text-muted">{{ name }}, {{ state }} {{ country}} </small></p>
</div>
</form>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried a jijna2 for loop, but I can't seem to get it working (removed from home.html above). Here is the loop I tried-

```
{% for site in site_code %}
 {{ site }}
{% endfor %}
```

Results without the loop-

[image]

What I would like is a list of all the Stoughton sites, not just the last one. Thank you for your time.

Results with the loop in home.html

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put these `site_code` that you calculate in the loop into a _list_ and pass this list into the context... (As it is you passing `site_code` will of course pass only the last variable of the loop, because it is the same variable you are overwriting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here can be used a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def lookup_code(request):
    locode_url = 'https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/un-locode/code-list_json/data/05f6ccfe0cd03ab51bed07273b982df9/code-list_json.json'
    try:
        city = request.GET.get('city')
        r = requests.get(locode_url)
        raw_data = (json.loads(r.content))
        site_codes = [
            {
                "city_code": res['Location'],   
                "country_code": res['Country'],
                "state": res['Subdivision'],
                "site_code": "%s-%s" % (res['Country'],res['Location']),
            } 
            for res in raw_data if res['Name'] == city
        ]
        return render(request, 'app_sitecode/home.html', {'site_codes': site_codes})
    except:
        return render(request, 'app_sitecode/home.html', {'cleartext':'', 'city':'INVALID CITY'})
```

template:

```
{% for site in site_codes %}
    {{ site.site_code }}, {{ site.state }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a smarter way. Thank you!

Comment: @CollinClark, Happy to help !